# BibLaTeX - The localization without a language key

Tags: biblatex, languages

Generally, we can do the localization by setting the *language* key in each .bib entry and using `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`([BibLaTeX Document](ftp://ftp.riken.go.jp/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p.204).

[Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) can generate .bib resources, but there is no way to include the *language* key in each entry.

My question is how to change the BibLaTeX references format for each language without a *language* key.

I know that BibTeX can get the multiple .bib resources.
Can BibLaTeX use different format settings in each .bib resource?
Or, is there any suggestion in order to do the localization without a *language* key?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Can it not generate arbitrary fields?  That seems like a serious shortcoming.... Another idea: if you can add a unique string to one of the accepted fields, you could use `\DeclareSourcemap` to remove it and then *add* language fields....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously it would be best for Mendeley to just allow to add the `langid` field for convenient language switching.

If you cannot have that, you might organise your bibliography in `.bib` files by language.
You then can add the `langid` field for each entry like this

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-en.bib}
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={english}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-de.bib}
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={ngerman}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-fr.bib}
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={french}]
    }
  }
}
```

Where we use `\perdatasource` to restrict the mapping to the appropriate `.bib` file.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman,french,english,british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, abbreviate=false, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-en.bib}
@book{abook,
  author     = {Ann Uthor},
  editor     = {Emily Ditor},
  translator = {Tracy R. Anslator},
  title      = {A Fancy Title},
  date       = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-de.bib}
@book{einbuch,
  author     = {Andrea Torin},
  editor     = {Herbert R. Ausgeber},
  title      = {Ein Titel},
  date       = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-fr.bib}
@book{livre,
  author     = {Amelie Uteur},
  editor     = {R. Édactrice},
  title      = {Titre},
  date       = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname-en.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-de.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-fr.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-en.bib}
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={english}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-de.bib}
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={ngerman}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-fr.bib}
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue={french}]
    }
  }
}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the language is different for all the entries.

---

Alternatively - thanks to @jon for the idea - you could also add a unique string to a field you can export to. In our example we add `[[<langid>]]` to the `title` field (where `<langid>` should expand to a language identifier `biblatex` or rather `babel`/`polyglossia` can cope with). The language string is then added to the `langid` field and deleted from the `title`.

Here, the mapping looks like this

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\s*\[\[(.+)\]\]}, final]
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue=\regexp{$1}]
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\s*\[\[(.+)\]\]}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}
```

And you add the language to the `.bib` entry like this

```
@book{einbuch,
  author     = {Andrea Torin},
  editor     = {Herbert R. Ausgeber},
  title      = {Ein Titel[[ngerman]]},
  date       = {2014},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman,french,english,british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, abbreviate=false, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{abook,
  author     = {Ann Uthor},
  editor     = {Emily Ditor},
  translator = {Tracy R. Anslator},
  title      = {A Fancy Title [[english]]},
  date       = {2015},
}
@book{einbuch,
  author     = {Andrea Torin},
  editor     = {Herbert R. Ausgeber},
  title      = {Ein Titel[[ngerman]]},
  date       = {2014},
}
@book{livre,
  author     = {Amelie Uteur},
  editor     = {R. Édactrice},
  title      = {Titre [[french]]},
  date       = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\s*\[\[(.+)\]\]}, final]
      \step[fieldset=langid, fieldvalue=\regexp{$1}]
      \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\s*\[\[(.+)\]\]}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```