# No bibtex style file for clickable links without displaying the url explicitly?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls

Having the same problem as [bibtex - how to have a web link without the url (ideally to have a link on the number)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102552/bibtex-how-to-have-a-web-link-without-the-url-ideally-to-have-a-link-on-the-n), I am wondering:

**Is there really no freely accessible bibtex style** (so as I do not have to edit neither bibliography items nor my bibtex style file) **which would use the url field to make the whole bibliography item** [change colour and become] **clickable without explicitly displaying the url?**

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102557/66983) is not a solution for me, as I do not want to add any additional text to my references.

The way Annals of Physics does it is what I am looking for:
[image]

If such a bibtex style does not exist, what is the simplest solution to achieve this result?

UPDATE:
To provide a code to work with, let us start with the example:

```
% pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{pascal,
  title={Pensees},
  author={Pascal, B. and Krailsheimer, A.},
  series={Penguin classics},
  url={http://books.google.cz/books?id=jakUTllF9G0C},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Penguin Books Limited}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
Give it a try: \cite{pascal}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Giving:[image]

UPDATE 2:
Using biblatex (and the same bibliography entry), we get:

```
      % pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
Give it a try: \cite{pascal}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the question is:
**How to make the url disappear and make the whole (or part) of the entry a link to the given url?**

Comment: The simplest solution would involve `biblatex`/`biber` rather than `bibtex`. It will not by default do what you want but is much more configurable. Moreover, there is an `eprint` field which is fantastic. (Short but still helpful if somebody can't click the link directly for some reason.)

Comment: @cfr Ok, so how would I implement the proposed biblatex/biber solution?

Comment: I'd start with `texdoc biblatex`. You haven't provided any code to work with...

Comment: Note that you've already said that one possible solution is incompatible with your class. But no indication of what that class is. A  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed here.

Comment: @wondering: Well, even that non-working-example could be a starting point here ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, mwe added:-)

Comment: @cfr My database is created by Mendeley, so I am afraid no eprint option possible. Maybe I should think about an alternative for Mendeley...

Comment: if you add option `url=false` in `biblatex` packages will remove the url from references section.

Comment: @AsisPattisahusiwa No, this does not work, the use of `\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}` does not give me a clickable link. Or did I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: No, you got what I mean.

Comment: @AsisPattisahusiwa Sorry, then I do not understand your comment. I am trying to replace the clickable url by a clickable reference pointing to that url (without displaying the url).

Comment: Mendeley sounds really annoying to use. A similar question came up recently that might be of interest. The [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227483/8528) shows a way to get a new field incorporated into the entry, which you could adapt to include an `eprint` field even if Mendeley won't let you export that field initially.

Comment: @jon Well, I have never tried any alternatives of Mendeley. But I don't think there is any other desktop client for such a comfortable work with the possibility of viewing the pdf's of the database entries, full-text search etc. There are, however, many features which need to be add/fixed and the process is really slow... I thought the acquisition by Elsevier, though it made me worry a lot, would at least make the developement quicker than before, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it really seems that there is no bibtex style with an easy implementation of the desired feature. Thanks to cfr I discovered biblatex/biber and the solution I like is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48409/66983 from question [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn). It has even more features than I wanted.