# Using Biblatex/biber, how to make each whole bibliography line-item a clickable hyperlink?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, urls, els-cas

I recently asked a very similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534216/when-using-elsarticle-cls-how-to-make-each-bibliography-item-a-clickable-hyperl) using `bibtex` and `natbib`. I got in touch with the journal's typesetters, who has asked me to use the `cas-sc.cls` file along with `biblatex/biber`, and pointed me to their official support portal [here](https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Elsarticle_-_CAS#Bibliography) which reiterates the advice to use `biblatex/biber`.

The requirement is that each bibliography item (i.e. the whole line entry) becomes a clickable hyperlink (using the doi field if available, else using the url field of the relevant key in the bib file). Additionally, the `doi` and `url` fields should not be typeset in the bibliography.

The bibliography style file I would like to use is [model1-num-names.bst](https://gist.github.com/krishnakumarg1984/762f4175c2d138d1e70e1061006ce0ca)

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{cas-sc}
\newdimen\bibsep 
\addbibresource{model1-num-names.bst} % please download the file from the gist URL (see question)

\begin{document}

\title[mode=title]{My paper title}
\tnotemark[1,2]

\tnotetext[1]{Title footnote 1: This document presents the results of the research project funded by the National Science Foundation: Placeholder. Replace with your own text.}

\tnotetext[2]{Title footnote 2: For example, a dedication. The second title footnote which is a longertext matter to fill through the whole text width andoverflow into another line in the footnotes area of thefirst page.}

%%% Authors' names, affiliations, physical addresses, email addresses & footnotes %%%%
\author[1]{First Author}[orcid=0000-0001-7511-2910]
\fnmark[1] 
\ead{firstemail_id@insti_1.edu}
\ead[url]{www.inst1.edu/author1}
\address[1]{Address of author with affiliation `a'}

\author[2]{Second Author}
\fnmark[2] 
\ead{secondemail_id@insti_2.edu}
\ead[url]{www.inst2.edu/author2}
\address[2]{Address of author with affiliation `b'}

\author[3]{Third Author} 
\fnmark[1,3]
\ead{thirdemail_id@insti_3.edu}
\ead[url]{www.inst3.edu/author3}

\address[3]{Utopia, Mars}

\fntext[fn1]{This is a footnote.}
\fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, this is a very long footnote and it should be a really long footnote. But this footnote is not yet sufficiently long enough to make twolines of footnote text.}
\fntext[fn3]{Yet another author footnote.}

\begin{abstract}
    The abstract of the paper goes here. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{abstract}

% Research highlights
\begin{highlights}
\item Research highlight 1
\item Research highlight 2
\end{highlights}

\begin{keywords}
    % Keywords go here in the form:  keyword \sep keyword
    Keywords \sep in \sep American \sep English
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}{\label{sec:intro}}
Blah

\section{Results and discussion}{\label{sec:results}}
Blah blah

\nocite{*}
% Command to typeset bibliography using biblatex/biber

\end{document}
```

The following bib contents may be used (let's call this `manuscript_references.bib`:

```
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of Methods for Deriving Atomic Charges from the
                  Electrostatic Potential and Moments},
  journal      = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@misc{elk,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {A Theory on {Brontosauruses}},
  year    = {1971},
  url     = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {{Aristotle's} {`De Motu Animalium'}},
  year         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  address      = {Princeton},
}
```

Comment: I think `els-cas` is incompatible with `biblatex`. To start off, if you don't load `natbib` the class will throw an error...

Comment: That is true. I observed it, but they really insist that I need to use `biblatex` and `biber`. Please see the support wiki page.  Since this question was about `biblatex`, I didn't want to confuse the readers by loading `natbib`. This is why I said minimal non-working example.

Comment: Yes, if you want `biblatex` then by no means you should load `natbib` (both serve the same purpose, so they are incompatible). My remark was more in the sense that it's weird for them to request one package if the class requires the other. That said, doing `\newdimen\bibsep` in the preamble makes the error go away...

Comment: If they want you to use `biblatex`, their template should definitely support this. As you found out, `biblatex` doesn't even load properly with the template. The example document that comes with the template on CTAN only mentions BibTeX, uses BibTeX-based code `\bibliographystyle` and another document http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/doc/elsdoc-cas.pdf explicitly says: "This class depends on the following packages for its proper functioning: 1. `natbib.sty` for citation processing;" ...

Comment: ... so I strongly suggest you get back to the person who told you to use `biblatex` and point out to them that with the current version of the template on CTAN `biblatex` can't be used properly. You may also want to get in touch with the maintainer of the `els-cas` bundle directly (if they are a different person from the one who told you to use `biblatex` in the first place).

Comment: **You will definitely not be able to use `model1-num-names.bst` or indeed any `.bst` file with `biblatex`.** `biblatex` uses a completely different method of defining citation and bibliography styles that does not rely on `.bst` files. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864

Comment: The "Please take a look at this page" more link in the `biblatex` section in https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Elsarticle_-_CAS#Bibliography leads to https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Model-wise_bibliographic_style_files which mainly offers `.bst` files for BibTeX (incompatible with `biblatex`) and doesn't mention `biblatex` or Biber once.