# Correct arXiv hyperlinks with BibLaTeX and Mendeley

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I use Mendeley to generate the *bibliography.bib* file and biblatex to process it. I noticed a problem with *arXiv* references for which the field *primaryClass* is defined. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{Witten1994,
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {hep-th/9411102},
author = {Witten, Edward},
eprint = {9411102},
month = {nov},
primaryClass = {hep-th},
title = {Monopoles and Four-Manifolds},
year = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\cite{Witten1994}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bibliogaphy entry was copied from the file generated by Mendeley. The code produces the following:

[image: Example]

However, when I click on the link, it takes me to https://arxiv.org/abs/9411102,
which does not exist. The correct hyperlink should be https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411102. My questions are:

1. How can I correct the hyperlink?
2. How can I get *arXiv:hep-th/9411102*, which is the correct arxivId, instead of *arXiv: 9411102 [hep-th]*?

Only solutions which do not require me to modify the bibliography file are acceptable.

Thank you very much for your help!

Update 1: This is the non-modified output generated by Mendeley.

```
@misc{Witten1994,
abstract = {Recent developments in the understanding of {\$}N=2{\$} supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory in four dimensions suggest a new point of view about Donaldson theory of four manifolds: instead of defining four-manifold invariants by counting {\$}SU(2){\$} instantons, one can define equivalent four-manifold invariants by counting solutions of a non-linear equation with an abelian gauge group. This is a ``dual'' equation in which the gauge group is the dual of the maximal torus of {\$}SU(2){\$}. The new viewpoint suggests many new results about the Donaldson invariants.},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {hep-th/9411102},
author = {Witten, Edward},
eprint = {9411102},
file = {:home/ylpu/Dropbox/Knihovna/files/Witten - 1994 - Monopoles and Four-Manifolds.pdf:pdf},
month = {nov},
primaryClass = {hep-th},
title = {{Monopoles and Four-Manifolds}},
url = {https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9411102.pdf http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411102},
year = {1994}
}
```

Update 2: I changed article to misc in the code above because the image was generated using misc and not article.

**Discussion about @article vs. @online/@misc:**

The options in Mendeley are either *Generic* or *Journal Article*; they produce *@misc* and *@article*, respectively. As far as I know there is no option for @online. I include below another example, where [1] is a citation of a journal article, and [2] and [3] are citations of the same article from arXiv using @misc and @article, respectively. I personally prefer @misc for arXiv articles because I do not see any reason for "In: (Nov. 1994)". On the other hand, I like "In:" for journal articles because it marks the beginning of the publication data - journal, volume, date, page.

[image: @article vs @misc]

Comment: `biblatex` would expect you to give it `eprint = {hep-th/9411102}` and `eprinttype = {arxiv}`. I believe you'd get expected results with that. That given, there's still the issue of how to convince Medley to do that...

Comment: While we are at it: `month = {nov},` should be `month = nov,` (without braces!), `month = {12},` or if you like `month = 12`. `month = {nov}` is wrong even though Biber salvages it, BibTeX on the other hand is stumped. The `biblatex` solution would be `date = {1994-11},` but that is not backwards compatible with BibTeX.

Comment: `@article` is equally wrong. Only papers published in a (scientific) journal should be `@article`s. If the paper on the arXiv was not published in a journal, `@online` is the better choice. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415115/35864. Furthermore the `url` field can only contain one URL. Two or more URLs will inevitably break and cause a mess.

Comment: Please complain loudly to the Mendeley developers about this. Especially if you (or your institution) are paying for an account. Going back though my answers I can find quite some problematic behaviours with Mendeley's export: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428959/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429297/35864 (could be a UI issue), https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286261/35864 (definitely Mendeley's fault), https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247874/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227460/35864

Comment: @moewe I disagree with that. *arXiv* should be considered as a journal, in this sense. Its pre-print status can optionally be indicated with: `pubstate = {\bibstring{prepublished}}`. There is no need to consider pre-prints as second-class objects, especially for citation purposes.

Comment: The "In: (Nov. 1994)" looks very clumsy to me. I think Coby Viner suggested adding `journal = {arXiv},` to arXiv-`@article`s to avoid this clumsiness. That certainly makes the output less awkward. We discussed the merits of using `@article` for arXiv entries below https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415117/35864 (as already commented below the answer here) but we couldn't come to a satisfying conclusion.

Comment: When Mendeley imports from arXiv, it sets the document type to Journal Article and leaves the journal field empty. Hence it produces exactly the clumsy output above :-D It seems like Mendeley, in its current state, definitely does not produce bib files suitable for actual articles; one should use it only as  a personal collection of literature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to give pre-2007 arXiv identifiers in `biblatex` is putting `eprinttype = {arxiv}` and `eprint = {<class>/<id>}`. So ideally your example would be

```
@online{Witten1994,
  author     = {Witten, Edward},
  title      = {Monopoles and Four-Manifolds},
  date       = {1994-11},
  eprint     = {hep-th/9411102},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
}
```

Note how I used the actually existing entry type `@online` instead of the non-existent `@generic`.

Papers that use the new, post-2007 scheme have the class in `eprintclass` and only the numerical identifier in the `eprint` field

```
@online{wassenberg,
  author       = {Wassenberg, Jan and Sanders, Peter},
  title        = {Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining},
  date         = {2010-08-17},
  version      = 1,
  eprinttype   = {arxiv},
  eprintclass  = {cs.DS},
  eprint       = {1008.2849v1},
}
```

This is consistent with the link always going to `https://arxiv.org/abs/<eprint>`.

For backwards compatibility reasons `archivePrefix` is an alias for `eprinttype`, so `archivePrefix = {arxiv}` is the same as `eprinttype = {arxiv}`. Furthermore `primaryclass` is an alias for `eprintclass`.

This explains what you are seeing: `arxivId` is not a know field and therefore ignored, `archivePrefix` becomes `eprinttype`, `primaryClass` becomes `eprintclass` and so you get the output that

```
  eprinttype   = {arxiv},
  eprintclass  = {hep-th},
  eprint       = {9411102},
```

would produce:

> arXiv: [9411102 [hep-th]](http://arxiv.org/abs/9411102)

with a link to http://arxiv.org/abs/9411102

---

Your `.bib` entries seems to be using an unintelligible mess of old and new formats together with fields unknown to `biblatex`.  **This should definitely be fixed in the `.bib` file.** If Mendeley produces this mess automatically, complain to the Mendeley developers. If some automatic citation export tool produced this mess ([Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864)), complain to the provider of the data. (At least if they claim to offer `biblatex`-compatible data. Otherwise they can hide behind the fact that there is no consensus amongst traditional BibTeX `.bst` files how to handle arXiv eprints - if they offer it at all.)

You can try and get Biber to repair some of the damage on the fly. The following works under the assumption that all old-style arXiv identifier are presented as in your question. In particular `arxivId` must contain the full link after `https://arxiv.org/abs/` in the form `<class>/<identifier>` and `archivePrefix` or `eprinttype` must be `arxiv`. The `primaryClass` will be discarded if a `/` is found in `arxivId` indicating we have a pre-2007 identifier.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=arxivId]
      \step[fieldset=eprint, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=eprint, match={/}, final]
      \step[fieldset=primaryClass, null]
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't do anything for new identifiers since I don't know how these look in your `.bib` file.

Comment: Your solution works! And it led me to the section "4.5.3 Dynamic Modification of Data" in the BibLaTeX manual, which I can study. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user32817 Of course it does ;-). But it is really only a bad kludge to patch up a seriously flawed `.bib` file on the fly. The real solution is to fix the source file. You can do quite a lot with source maps, but the point is that *you shouldn't have to do some of these things in the first place if Mendeley were to export properly formatted `.bib` files*.

Comment: OK, I will write a complaint to Mendeley developers.

Comment: @user32817 Good. Note that as I say in the answer there is really no "this is how an arXiv `eprint` must look like in `.bib` files" rule in the *BibTeX* documentation (BibTeX was developed before arXiv existed). Consequently nor all BibTeX (`.bst`) styles that add arXiv support do it in the same way. But if Mendeley claims to export for `biblatex` it should conform to the data model and its usage as documented in the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: *arXiv* papers should really be cited as `@article`, in my opinion, optionally with `pubstate = {\bibstring{prepublished}}`.

Comment: @CobyViner (and for the benefit of others reading this) I answered below https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415117/35864